# How do I create an image of a object that has not displayed yet

Tags: c#

In my project I have a number of pages. Each page is a panel with a number of usercontrols contained within. I would like to have a thumbnail image of the yet to be displayed panel and it's contents. How do I go about doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the DrawToBitmap function of the panel would work for this purpose.

Something to the effect of:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel.Bounds.Width, panel.Bounds.Height);
panel.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panel.ClientRectangle);
bmp.Save("c:\\test.bmp");
bmp.Dispose();
```

**Edit** - Updated to more appropriate sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly how to get the image, but you can still update controls (or a form) without the them being visible.  But I do not believe there is anything built into .NET that would allow you to take an image of a form without actually rendering it to the screen.  Maybe through the GDI?